# "OR" operator in regex, in express routing

Tags: regex, node.js, express

i want both **"/"** and **"/home"** path, **direct** user to **same page**("/home").
How i can write this with **regex** in **express routing**. i tried this:
`router.route('/|/home')`
but it dose not work.

Comment: Try `router.route(/^\/(home)?$/)`

Comment: sr. it works. tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
router.route(/^\/(home)?$/)
```

The regex matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `\/` - a slash
- `(home)?` - an optional sequence of literal chars `home`
- `$` - end of string.

Basically, it is the same as `/^(\/|\/home)$/` with 2 alternatives, `\/` and `\/home` that are both anchored at the start and end of the string, just the optional group (i.e. `(home)?`) is a much more optimal way to match the two alternatives.

Note that the non-capturing group can also be used here (and even is preferred), but it is a tiny bit less readable: `/^\/(?:home)?$/`.